# Getting curated content using streaming API

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I cam across one third party API which provides organized twitter data as per user request.

example

`http://api.frrole.com/v1/curated-content?location=India&contenttype=link&category=sports&orderby=popularity&minrt=10&resultcount=100&apikey=4534sdg34343`

It give top 100 tweets from india, which contains link in tweets and falling into sports category and having minimum rt count =10.

Can someone tell me how does this work? It gives json data as result. Does this result comes directly via twitter streaming APIs or third party's own data base?

Is there any way for streaming API to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely coming from their database. They are consuming the data from the Streaming API or another API and then applying their categorization to it, then giving you the ability to access it from an API.

Some of the criteria above you could get from the Streaming API such as the filter_level (to find top Tweets) but you wouldn't be able to get that whole set of requirements (especially the sports categorization).